# ngHint as gulp task

Tags: angularjs, gulp, angularjs-ng-hint

[ngHint](https://github.com/angular/angular-hint) is an angularjs package, which provides run-time hinting for AngularJS applications. I want to include that as an gulp task, just like js-hint and get the report of issues on node console.

How can I integrate ngHint with gulp?